# Связь блока с чекбоксом

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста,как сделать такую тему -

есть N-ое количество чекбоксов, напротив каждого чекбокса div-block в котором указана цена, нужно сделать так,чтобы внизу выводилась суммарная стоимость отмеченных продуктов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item input')).map(e => e.addEventListener('change', handler));
});

function handler(){
  let cost      = parseFloat(this.dataset.price),
      view      = document.querySelector('#totalCost'),
      totalCost = parseFloat(view.textContent.substring(1)),
      newCost   = '';
  
  if(this.checked)
    newCost = (totalCost + cost).toFixed(2);
  else
    newCost = (totalCost - cost).toFixed(2);
  
  view.textContent = `$${newCost}`;
}
```

```css
.price{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
  <div class='item'>
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' data-price='10' />
      <div class='price'>$10</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' data-price='0.05' />
      <div class='price'>$0.05</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' data-price='3.83' />
      <div class='price'>$3.83</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' data-price='56' />
      <div class='price'>$56</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' data-price='0.26' />
      <div class='price'>$0.26</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <label>
      <input type='checkbox' data-price='359.15' />
      <div class='price'>$359.15</div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<span>Total cost: </span><strong id='totalCost'>$0.00</strong>
```